# amCharts manipulating data from dataLoader

Tags: javascript, amcharts

So I have a chart from amCharts which loads data from a CSV using the dataLoader plugin.

However, when using dataLoader, the `datapPovider` variable doesn't seem to be set anywhere, so how can I access the data currently being displayed in the graph?

This is so I can sort it onclick (external HTML button).

When I import with JSON, this is easy to do because I just make the change to the `dataProvider` variable and `validateData()`, but there doesn't seem to be an option like that for dataLoader.

Comment: That does not seem to be a correct assumption. Data Loader plugin sets `dataProvider` for the chart after the data is loaded. You can access and manipulate it just like you normally would. Of course you have to wait until the data finishes loading to do that.

Comment: that makes sense. Dataprovider kept returning null because I had it running synchronously with the dataloader. It needs to finish loading before use. Thanks, and sorry for the silly question